# Erro ao Adicionar Controller com views usando Entity Framework em Asp.NET

Tags: entity-framework, asp

Ao tentar adicionar aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCEntity.Models
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Login { get; set; }
        public String Senha { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Arquivo Data onde faço as configurações do DB:

```
using System.Web;
using MVCEntity.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MVCEntity.Data
{
    public class TestandoMVCContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestandoMVCContext() : base ("TestandoMVC_Desenv")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Linhas adicionadas no meu Web.config:

```
  <connectionString>
    <add name="TestandoMVC_Desenv" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Projetos\asp\MVCEntity\MVCEntity\App_Data\TestandoMVC_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionString>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
       invariant="System.Data.SqlClient"
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer"
       type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data,   
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que tudo parece! Após horas pesquisando, isso foi nada mais que a falta de um "s" na tag `<connectionString>` que ficaria `<connectionStrings>`

Falta de atenção minha!

No meu caso em si, porém pesquisando em outros fóruns e até mesmo no stackoverflow (EN) existem vários outros tipos de problemas que podem ocasionar o mesmo!

Segue o link para outros tipos de soluções: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576294/application-cant-scaffold-items?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa